# Angular appliying filter to custom data source

Tags: angular, filter, datatable

I created my angular datatable using `ng generate @angular/material:material-table --name <component-name>` command. I followed some tutorial on how to fill this datatable using http request. I tried to apply some filteration on the datatable as well.

here is my op-dta-datasource.ts file code.

```
export interface OpDataSecondItem {
  id: number;
  title:string;
  close_date:Date;
}
export class OpDataSecondDataSource extends DataSource<OpDataSecondItem> {
  data: OpDataSecondItem[];
  paginator: MatPaginator;
  sort: MatSort;

  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  connect(): Observable<OpDataSecondItem[]> {
    // Combine everything that affects the rendered data into one update
    // stream for the data-table to consume.
    const dataMutations = [
      observableOf(this.data),
      this.paginator.page,
      this.sort.sortChange
    ];

    return merge(...dataMutations).pipe(map(() => {
      return this.getPagedData(this.getSortedData([...this.data]));
    }));
  }
......
```

it is my op-dta.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'op-data-second',
  templateUrl: './op-data-second.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./op-data-second.component.css']
})
export class OpDataSecondComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnInit {
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
  @ViewChild(MatTable) table: MatTable<OpDataSecondItem>;

  dataSource: OpDataSecondDataSource;
  searchKey: string;
  displayedColumns = ['id', 'title','close_date','published_date'];
  
  constructor(private service: HttpserviceService){}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource = new OpDataSecondDataSource();
     this.service.getOps('').subscribe((data:OpDataSecondItem[])=>{
       this.dataSource.data =  data;
     });
    
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.table.dataSource = this.dataSource;
  }


  onSearchClear() {
    this.searchKey = "";
    this.applyFilter();
  }

  applyFilter() {
    this.dataSource.data['title'].filter = this.searchKey.trim().toLowerCase();
  }
}
```

and my html code.

```
<div class="search-div">
  <mat-form-field class="search-form-field" >
    <input matInput [(ngModel)]="searchKey" placeholder="Search" autocomplete="off" (keyup)="applyFilter()">
    <button mat-button matSuffix mat-icon-button aria-label="Clear"*ngIf="searchKey"  (click)="onSearchClear()">
      <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
    </button>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>


<div class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <table   mat-table class="full-width-table" matSort aria-label="Elements">
    <!-- Id Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header><strong>Id</strong>   </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> <span>{{row.id}}</span></td>
    </ng-container>

   .............

  <mat-paginator #paginator
      [length]="dataSource?.data.length"
      [pageIndex]="0"
      [pageSize]="10"
      [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 50]"
      showFirstLastButtons>
  </mat-paginator>
</div>
```

the filter method I wrote is not working, i saw some codes they were using mattabledatasource which i didn't understand and I could not transform my code to that way. can any one help me how can I write the filter method that works , and how to transfrom my code in order to use MatTableDataSource in such a way which my current modules don't break.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();
    this.service.getOps('').subscribe((data: OpDataSecondItem[]) => {
        this.dataSource.data = data;
    });

    this.dataSource.filterPredicate = function (data, filter: string): boolean {
        return data.title.toLowerCase().includes(filter);
    };
}

applyFilter() {
    this.dataSource.filter = this.searchKey.trim().toLowerCase();;
  }
```

Comment: it says, Property 'filterPredicate' does not exist on type 'OpDataSecondDataSource'

Comment: Now I have edited my answer. Please check it now

Comment: now it saysType 'MatTableDataSource<unknown>' is missing the following properties from type 'OpDataSecondDataSource': getPagedData, getSortedDatats(2739)

Comment: change this line -> dataSource: OpDataSecondDataSource to dataSource: any;

Answer (score 0):

```
 <app-search [from]="searchFrom" [setSearchString]="searchString" (filterEvent)="applyFilter($event)"
          (reloadEvent)="refreshList($event)"></app-search>
```

```
  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    filterValue = filterValue.trim(); // Remove whitespace
    filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase(); // Datasource defaults to lowercase matches
    // this.configProdService.dataSource.filter = filterValue;
    this.comonService.setPageDetails({ offset: this.offset });
    const pagination: any = {
      offset: 0,
      limit: 10,
      filter: filterValue
    };
    this.getCampaignsList(pagination);
  }
```